# what is the meaning of + symbol in iOS file naming?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have seen some examples of iOS project, but i am a little confused with the naming rule of the file. What is the meaning of the + symbol in iOS naming rule? In what case we should use this symbol.

[image]

And what does it mean to put Draggle within ().

[image]

Hopefully someone can help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are categories

see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

the "draggable" is a category of UICollectionView

here's  a snippent from apple:

> If you need to add a method to an existing class, perhaps to add
>   functionality to make it easier to do something in your own
>   application, the easiest way is to use a category.
>
> The syntax to declare a category uses the @interface keyword, just
>   like a standard Objective-C class description, but does not indicate
>   any inheritance from a subclass. Instead, it specifies the name of the
>   category in parentheses, like this:
>
> ```
> @interface ClassName (CategoryName)
>
>
>
> @end
> ```

Here's another example

```
#import "UIView+Roundify.h"


@implementation UIView (Roundify)

-(void)addRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadii:(CGSize)radii {
    CALayer *tMaskLayer = [self maskForRoundedCorners:corners withRadii:radii];
    [[self layer] setMask:tMaskLayer];
}

-(CALayer*)maskForRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadii:(CGSize)radii {
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    UIBezierPath *roundedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:
                                 maskLayer.bounds byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:radii];
    maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.path = [roundedPath CGPath];

    return maskLayer;
}

@end
```

Header

```
@interface UIView (Roundify)

-(void)addRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadii:(CGSize)radii;
-(CALayer*)maskForRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadii:(CGSize)radii;

@end
```

this means that when we import this file, we can call method "addRoundCorners" to a UIView